# Concatenate columns after matching column names

Tags: python, pandas

I want to concatenate set of two similar named columns of the dataset. The columns are something like below:

```
URO_Brand1_Target,URO_Brand1,URO_Brand2_Target,URO_Brand2,URO_Brand3_Target
```

These could come in the dataset in no particular order. Now based on the condition if column name "URO_Brand1" is contained in column name "URO_Brand1_Target", I have to concatenate the two columns. And this I have to do for all set of similar columns.

Something like this:

```
URO_Brand1_Target URO_Brand1   Concatenate(URO_Brand1, URO_Brand1_Target)
     95%      CIG0002069   CIG0002069,95%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`. Assume you have a `df`:

```
  URO_Brand1_Target  URO_Brand1 URO_Brand2_Target  URO_Brand2
0               95%  something1               90%  something2
```

Iterate through groups using `groupby`:

```
for k, d in df.groupby(df.columns.str[:10], axis=1):
    tmp = d.sort_index(1)
    df['Concatenate(%s)' % ', '.join(d.columns)] = tmp.apply(','.join, 1)
```

Output:

```
  URO_Brand1_Target  URO_Brand1 URO_Brand2_Target  URO_Brand2  \
0               95%  something1               90%  something2   

  Concatenate(URO_Brand1_Target, URO_Brand1)  \
0                             something1,95%   

  Concatenate(URO_Brand2_Target, URO_Brand2)  
0                             something2,90%
```

Comment: # compute the result using the series generator
--> 248         self.apply_series_generator()
    249 
    250         # wrap results

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    275             try:
    276                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 277                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    278                     keys.append(v.name)
    279             except Exception as e:

TypeError: ('sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: hi @Chris, just to mention I have some other columns before the URO columns that I don't want to concatenate.This Apparently is concatenating all the columns.

Comment: @Aditi it is indeed. It will groupby all the columns with their first 10 letters. Can you share `df.columns`? Also for the above error, change the `apply` part to `apply(lambda x: ','.join(str(i) for i in x), 1)`.